# op amp code I/P E/SL I/SL

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm quite new in the field. I need to purchase an op amp chips MCP6004, but I found different version (seems not listed in datasheet)
[enter link description here](https://hken.rs-online.com/web/c/semiconductors/amplifiers-comparators/op-amps/?searchTerm=mcp6004&redirect-relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E53656172636847656E65726963266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C7061727469616C26706D3D5E5B5C707B4C7D5C707B4E647D2D2C2F255C2E5D2B2426706F3D31313326736E3D592673723D2673743D4B4559574F52445F53494E474C455F414C5048415F4E554D455249432673633D592677633D4E4F4E45267573743D6D637036303034267374613D6D63703630303426&r=f&searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22:true%7D)

- MCP6004-**I/P** Microchip,, Op Amp, RRIO, 1MHz, 3 V, 5 V, 14-Pin PDIP
- MCP6004-**E/SL** Microchip,, Op Amp, RRIO, 1MHz, 3 V, 5 V, 14-Pin SOIC
- MCP6004-**I/SL** Microchip,, Op Amp, RRIO, 1MHz, 3 V, 5 V, 14-Pin SOIC

May I know what I/P, E/SL and I/SL mean? What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The part is available for two different temperature ranges: 'I' (industrial) and 'E' (extended).

The second part of the code identifies the package. 'P' means a PDIP, for example.

The datasheet is your friend for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the information comes at the end of the datasheet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Page 39 of the datasheet is headed "PRODUCT IDENTIFICATION SYSTEM".  It describes how the full part number is formed, and what the suffixes mean.

Most IC (and many other) datasheets have similar tables near the end.